# Cannot hear sound through headphone with Ubuntu 22.04 on certain machine

Tags: sound, 22.04, headphones

I installed Ubuntu on a Samsung T7 SSD (just "Linux to go"), and I have 2 machines (a laptop and a desktop both with Windows 10 on their SSDs).

> Linux kernel version: 5.19.0-50-generic, and using linux-modules-5.19.0-50-generic

Here's the condition of my headphones:

| mach \ os | ubuntu22.04 | win10 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| laptop | works well | works well |
| desktop | headphone and output detected, but can't here sound | works well |

I examined the situation of "Ubuntu 22.04 on my desktop":

1. settings - sound output can detect the headphones "Headphone USB Audio" (aux interface but USB Audio). P.S. and I can hear sound through "Speakers USB Audio"

   [image: pic-settings]
2. pavucontrol can see the sound output bar dance when playing a video.

   [image: pic-pavucontrol]

   [image: pic-config]